# Check if point is inside boundaries

Tags: python, gis, shapefile, fiona

I have a list of points describing the boundaries of Spain. I want to be able to tell whether a pair of lat,lon is within these boundaries. I have tried the following:

```
import shapefile
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import MultiPoint, Point, Polygon
from shapely.geometry.polygon import Polygon
sf = shapefile.Reader(r"\ESP_adm0.shp")
shapes = sf.shapes()
lat = []; lon = []
for i in range(len(shapes[0].points)):
    lon.append(shapes[0].points[i][0]);lat.append(shapes[0].points[i][1])
```

I know I am retrieving the points, because I'm able to plot and get the desired results:

```
plt.plot(lon,lat,'.', ms=0.1)
```

(plot in the link below)
[plot result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7bnD.png)

I do the following to get the poitns into a polygon:

```
    coords = list(zip(lat,lon))
    spain_pol = Polygon(coords)
```

And then I use the contains function, always getting false.

```
    spain_pol.contains(Point(0,42))
    spain_pol.contains(Point(42,0))
```

These both return false. In fact I haven't been able to get a single point I've tried to return a True.

I have tried all sorts of things, and I think I must be missing something fundamental. Perhaps the facts Spain has islands and there's more than one polygon is the problem? I'm lost. Any help welcome.

Comment: Have you tried the code with a simpler polygon (like a square)?

Comment: After thoroughly reading the doc, your code seems good. The only problem I see that could occur is because the Polygon is poorly declared (I haven't looked that up).

Comment: @WilliamBurnham I have tried it with a very simple 4 vertices polygon, and it works. I think the problem may be related to the fact this is in fact a multipolygon.

Comment: @JordiMuñoz Are you able to provide the shape file you're using? I'd like to give it a try with your data if possible.

Comment: I managed to get the result I was looking for. I think my problem was the multipolygon character of the data. Here's the link to get the files:http://www.gadm.org/country choose Spain and shapefile. I unzipped and got the adm0 since all I need are country boundaries. I'll try posting an answer to my own quesiton. Thank you anyway!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case someone else has the same issue. The following code worked perfectly:

```
import fiona
from shapely.geometry import MultiPoint, Point, Polygon,shape
from shapely.geometry.polygon import Polygon

multipol = fiona.open(r"C:\Users\Jordi\Downloads\ESP_adm_shp\ESP_adm0.shp")
multi = next(iter(multipol))

point = Point(0,42)
point.within(shape(multi['geometry']))
```

This returns a very welcome "True" :)

Comment: I think you could remove the `import shapefile` line, as it is not used anymore.